# How can I debug this code which intends to calclulate the sum of following series upto nth term(parameter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

```
    def series_sum(n):
       if n == 0:
           return 0.00
       s=0.00
       j=0.00
       for i in n:
           
           s = s + (1/j)
           j = j + 3
        
       print(round(s,2))
```

> TypeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 series_sum(2)
>
> in series_sum(n)
> 4     s=0.00
> 5     j=0.00
> ----> 6     for i in n:
> 7
> 8         s = s + (1/j)
>
> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
> This is what I mean : Series: 1 + 1/4 + 1/7 + 1/10 + 1/13 + 1/16 > >+... and this has to be rounded up to 2 decimal points

Comment: Do you mean ```for i in range(n):```? The error is obvious.

Comment: and It's obvious that I have to say THANK YOU :-) @Sujay

Comment: Sorry for disturbing again. why does the program checker passes all cases but tells me: '2.4' should equal '2.40'
0.0 should equal '0.00'   ?   @Sujay

Comment: You can use f-string formatting: `print(f"{round(s,2):.2f}")`

Comment: Ok I think you should remove the second 0 and try. Also, you should consider adding 3 to j before division else you will face a zero division error

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Solved Saviour!

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to iterate over an integer `n` yo need to turn  `for i in n:` to:  `for i in range(n):`

Comment: Yes, exactly. but now the problem is that the program checker gives me this error: '2.4' should equal '2.40' 0.0 should equal '0.00'

Comment: when I run the code it gives me a division by 0 error beace when it first runs j=0 and you are dividing 1/j

Comment: I solved it like this:
`
def series_sum(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0.00
    s=0.00
    j=1.00
    for i in range(n):
        
        s = s + (1/j)
        j = j + 3
    
   # print(str(round(s,3)))
    return(f"{round(s,2):.2f}")
         
`

Comment: yeah, that's how did. and now everything works?